# Validation Rule Not Working - Update Stage Requires Next Step to be Updated, Update Next Step and Get Same Validation Error

Tags: validation

I've seen others put a validation rule in place that requires the "Next Step" text field to be updated prior to the Stage Change unless it is Closed Won or Closed Lost. When I test the code below, the syntax says no errors found.

For testing, it works if I change the Stage to Closed Won, Closed Lost, Closed - Subscription Cancelled. That's the easy part as it doesn't ask for the Next Step field to be changed.

When I try to change to any other stage, the validation error appears like it should. BUT, when I then change the Next Step text, SAVE, and try to then change the Stage, I'm still getting the same error that the Next Step needs to be updated. What am I missing here?

```
AND(
    NOT(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won') || 
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Lost') ||    
        ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed - Subscription Cancelled')
    ),
    ISCHANGED(StageName),
    NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems pretty cut and dried based on your description.

This part of your validation formula

```
ISCHANGED(StageName),
NOT(ISCHANGED(NextStep))
```

means that you must change `NextStep` at the same time that your `StageName` is changing. You can't do those in separate save operations.

Validation rules alone can't do what you're describing (checking the previous state of a record for a previous save operation). I'm sure it'd be possible to do with some combination of validation rule and a trigger or before-save record triggered flow, but that sounds like more work than it's worth (and also a poor UX choice).

If you're really intent on forcing your users to do things in this particular order (as opposed to just making them update the next step at the same time as they change the stage), then a multi-step *screen flow* is probably better suited to the task.